# Pygame - speed variable cannot change from 5

Tags: python, pygame

I have absolutely no idea why, but when I try to change my `speed` variable from `5` to any other number, the whole thing hangs after one repetition.

My game is just a rectangle that is controlled by the mouse, and it has to go between two walls that have randomly spawned heights. Here is my main function:

```
def main():

    pygame.init()

    # Game sounds
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)

    song = "Music/boss.WAV"
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.constants.USEREVENT)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    passSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sound Effects/passPillar.wav")
    passSound.set_volume(0.3)
    levelUpSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sound Effects/levelUp.wav")
    levelUpSound.set_volume(0.5) 

    # Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
    width = 1000
    height = 800
    size = [width, height]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("boxes")

    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False

    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Hide the mouse cursor
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    # the player and its variables
    playerDimension = 50

    playerX = width/4

    playerScore = 0

    playerLevel = 1

    scoreBarWidth = 50

    # the walls and their variables
    extraWidth = 70

    wallWidth = playerDimension/2

    wallHeight_1 = randint( (height/5) , (height*4/5) )
    wallHeight_2 = height - wallHeight_1 - playerDimension+extraWidth

    wall_Y_1 = 0
    wall_Y_2 = wallHeight_1 + playerDimension+extraWidth

    walls_X = width - wallWidth    

    speed = 5

    # Game over and Intro screen
    gameOver = False

    introScreen = True

    # Fonts
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Avenir Next", 26)

    titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Avenir Next", 36)

    # Game loop
    while not done:

        # ALL EVENT PROCESSING
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                done = True

            elif event.type == pygame.constants.USEREVENT:

                # When the song stops playing, start song again
                pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
                pygame.mixer.music.play()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_r:

                    if gameOver:

                        gameOver = False

                        introScreen = True

                        playerLevel = 1
                        playerScore = 0

                        walls_X = width - wallWidth

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    if introScreen:

                        introScreen = False

                        levelUpSound.play()

        # ALL GAME LOGIC

        # GET MOUSE POSITION
        if not gameOver:

            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            y = pos[1]

        if not gameOver and not introScreen:

            # Format is x,y,w,h twice for both rects
            touchingUpper = collisionDetect(playerX, y, playerDimension, playerDimension, walls_X, wall_Y_1, wallWidth, wallHeight_1)

            touchingLower = collisionDetect(playerX, y, playerDimension, playerDimension, walls_X, wall_Y_2, wallWidth, wallHeight_2)

            gameOver = touchingUpper or touchingLower

            if walls_X == 0: # Move wall back to start and change heights

                wallHeight_1 = randint( (height/5) , (height*4/5) )
                wallHeight_2 = height - wallHeight_1 - playerDimension+extraWidth

                wall_Y_1 = 0
                wall_Y_2 = wallHeight_1 + playerDimension+extraWidth

                walls_X = width - wallWidth

            else:

                walls_X = walls_X - speed

            if walls_X == playerX:

                playerScore += 1

                if playerScore < 5:

                    passSound.play()

                elif playerScore == 5:

                    playerScore = 0

                    playerLevel += 1

                    levelUpSound.play()

            scoreBarWidth = playerScore*50



        # ALL CODE TO DRAW
        screen.fill(screenColour)

        # the player
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, playerColour, [playerX, y, playerDimension, playerDimension], 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, wallColour, [walls_X, wall_Y_1, wallWidth, wallHeight_1])#the upper wall
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, wallColour, [walls_X, wall_Y_2, wallWidth, wallHeight_2])#the lower wall

        for i in range(0, playerLevel):

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, levelsColour, [20 + (i*40), 20, 30, 30], 2) #levels

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, scorebarColour, [20, 60, scoreBarWidth, 30], 0) #scorebar filler
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, scorebarOutlineColour, [20, 60, 5*50, 30], 2) #scorebar outline

        if gameOver:

            text1 = titleFont.render("Game Over!", True, wallColour)
            text1_rect = text1.get_rect()
            text1_x = screen.get_width() * 1.7 / 3 - text1_rect.width / 2
            text1_y = screen.get_height() * 1.2 / 3 - text1_rect.height / 2
            screen.blit(text1, [text1_x, text1_y])

            text2 = font.render("You reached level " + str(playerLevel) + ".", True, wallColour)
            text2_rect = text2.get_rect()
            text2_x = screen.get_width() * 1.7 / 3 - text2_rect.width / 2
            text2_y = screen.get_height() / 2 - text2_rect.height / 2 
            screen.blit(text2, [text2_x, text2_y])

            text3 = font.render("Press R to restart.", True, wallColour)
            text3_rect = text3.get_rect()
            text3_x = screen.get_width() * 1.7 / 3 - text3_rect.width / 2
            text3_y = screen.get_height() * 1.8 / 3 - text3_rect.height / 2 
            screen.blit(text3, [text3_x, text3_y])

        elif introScreen:

            text1 = titleFont.render("Press Space to start!", True, wallColour)
            text1_rect = text1.get_rect()
            text1_x = screen.get_width() / 2 - text1_rect.width / 2
            text1_y = screen.get_height() * 1 / 3 - text1_rect.height / 2
            screen.blit(text1, [text1_x, text1_y])

        # Update the screen
        pygame.display.flip()

        # Limit frames per second
        clock.tick(200)

    # quit.
    pygame.quit()
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? The ultimate goal is to make the speed proportional to the playerLevel, to increase the difficulty over time.

Comment: have you tried tracing through the program to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if walls_X == 0: # Move wall back to start and change heights
```

use

```
if walls_X <= 0: # Move wall back to start and change heights
```

---

Why?

You use the variable speed only in one place:

```
walls_X = walls_X - speed
```

The initial value for `walls_X` is `975` (`width - wallWidth`) and then you repeatedly decrease it by `speed` - for `speed == 5` to `970, 965, 960, 955...`

The problem arises when you test the value of `walls_X` - in the statement:

```
if walls_X == 0: # Move wall back to start and change heights
```

If `speed` is *not* a divisor of `975` (i. e. it is different from `1, 3, 5, 13, 15, ...`) `walls_X` will never reach `0` and your test `walls_X == 0` will never pass.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be name shadowing something. I managed to reproduce your error (although I had to create all the colours and comment out the sounds), but when I renamed speed to wall_speed everything started to work